# Difference between GridSearchCV and Cross_Val_Score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I have a binary time series classification problem.

Since it is a time series, I can't just `train_test_split` my data. So, I used the object `tscv = TimeSeriesSplit()` from this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit), and got something like this:

[image]

I can see from [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) that i can pass as parameter my split strategy `cv = tscv`. But my question is, whats the difference between `GridSearchCV` and `coss_val_score`? Using one of them is enough to train/test my model? or should i use both? First the `GridSearchCV` to get the best hyperparamaters and then the `cross_val_score`?

Comment: They are essentially doing the same jobs but in different ways. In fact, the `GridSearchCV` itself uses the `cross_val_score` for finding the optimized combination of parameters. GridSearch is known to be a very slow method of tuning your hyperparameters and you are much better off sticking with `RandomSearchCV` or the more advanced Bayesian Hyperparameter Optimization methods

Comment: @meti then the cross-validation used by GridsearchCV is only used to find the best hyperparameters or also to calculate the metrics of the model (such as the roc_auc) with cross-validation?
After GridsearchCV() do we need to use cross_validate() ? Or is it already included on it?

Comment: @skan If you utilize GridsearchCV, it will furnish you with the most optimal hyperparameter based on your preferred metrics. However, if you wish to obtain a report on a specific metric such as ROC_CURVE, you will need to provide it separately along with the best combination of hyperparameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grid search is a method to evaluate models by using different hyperparameter settings (the values of which you define in advance). Your `GridSearch` can use cross validation (hence, `GridSearchCV` exists) in order to deliver a final score for the the different parameter settings of your model. After the training and the evaluation (after the grid search has finished), you can take a look at the parameters with which your model performed best (by taking a look at the attribute `best_params_dict`).So, Grid search is basically a brute forcing strategy in which you run the model with all possible hyperparameter combinations.
With `coss_val_score` you don't perform the grid search (you don't use the strategy mentioned above with all predefined params), but you get the score after the cross-validation.
I hope it is now clear.

Comment: But the ```.scores``` of both are sometimes drastically different. A mean of ```coss_val_score`.score``with k=5 maybe around 0.5, whereas as that of ```GridSearchCV``` could stay very high. Any idea why that is the case ?

Comment: It should be because of the parameters (since in the gridsearch you might use other params compared to the cv only). Give me a concrete example.

Comment: Then the cross-validation used by GridsearchCV is only used to find the best hyperparameters or also to calculate the metrics of the model (such as the roc_auc) with cross-validation? After GridsearchCV() do we need to use cross_validate() ? Or is it already included on it?